# Privileges list is not quite wide enough to prevent overflow, and/or inconsistent between browsers

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

When I go to [the privileges page](https://android.stackexchange.com/privileges), "remove new user restrictions" in the list on the right side overflows into the percentage column, forcing a wrap.  This in in Chrome 13.

[image: screenshot 1]

In IE8, I see different behavior; each percentage is on the line following the name of the privilege, instead of being on the same line.  This occurs everywhere in the list, but here's the bottom three again:

[image: screenshot 2]

When I click the "remove new user restrictions" link, the bolded text wraps:

[image: screenshot 3]

Firefox 5.0.1, 6.0, and 6.0.2 show the normal list correctly, with the percentage on the same line as the name of the privilege.  However, when I click the "remove new user restrictions" link, the text becomes bolded and mushes into the percentage:

[image: screenshot 4]

My resolution is 1050 x 1680, and I'm using Windows XP.

---

Edit:

## **BUMP!**

Comment: For what its worth, I'm seeing that too. (Chrome 15.0.874.102)

Comment: For what it's worth Firefox 7.01 on Win7x64 shows it all fine now, with none of the "mushing" you were seeing when I click the "remove new user restrictions" link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The privileges pages has been completely redesigned since 2011, so this bug is no longer reproducible.  Not that I didn't believe you ;-)